# PowerShell: Mover ficheros desde un directorio origen a varios directorios

Tags: powershell

He empezado con PowerShell hace poco y no lo controlo mucho.

Tengo la necesidad de hacer un script para un amigo que tiene un laboratorio, esto es lo que queremos hacer:

Las máquinas de laboratorio generan un informe que se coloca en un directorio como el siguiente

*X:\xxxx\xxxx\analisis*

Los ficheros que se generan tienen la siguiente estructura:

*20210708_1003.5_A_ddddd_1.txt*

Donde los campos significan lo siguiente:

- Fecha: 20210708
- Código del cliente: 1003.5
- Tipo de análisis: A
- Código del análisis: ddddd
- Versión del análisis: 1 (2,3,...)

Tenemos una estructura de directorios como sigue:

X:\xxxx\xxxx\analisis\1003.5 (para el cliente 1003.5)
X:\xxxx\xxxx\analisis\1004.5 (para el cliente 1004.5)

Y más directorios, uno por cada cliente existente.

Y queremos mover los ficheros que se realizan en una mañana (o cada ciertas horas) desde la carpeta "analisis" a la carpeta de cada cliente (cómo en el nombre del fichero generado está el cliente pues tenemos el dato.)

Por el momento he realizado la siguiente consulta

```
#PowerShell Mover ficheros de análisis a las carpetas de los clientes XXX
    $Excluidos = @("*1005.5*")
    #$Incluidos = @("*1003.5*","*1004.5*")
    $Directorioorigen = "x:\xxxx\xxxx\analisis\*"
    $Ficherosamover = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directorioorigen -Exclude $Excluidos -File
    ForEach ($Ficherosamover in $Ficherosamover)
    {
        $Archivo = $_.Name
        $Archivo
        $ArchivoDesglosado = $Archivo.Split("_")
        #$ArchivoDesglosado[0]
        #$ArchivoDesglosado[1]
        #$ArchivoDesglosado[2]
        #$ArchivoDesglosado[3]
        #$ArchivoDesglosado[4]
        $Cliente = $ArchivoDesglosado[1]
        #$Cliente
        $Tipoanalisis = $ArchivoDesglosado[2]
        #$Tipoanalisis
        $Año = $ArchivoDesglosado[0]
        #$Año
        Move-Item $Archivo x:\xxxx\xxxx\analisis\$Cliente*\$TipoAnalisis\$Año
    }
```

Soy muy explicito con el código pero es para aprender y expresar bien la idea de lo que quiero hacer.
Tengo claro que el problema lo tengo en el bucle, ya que si he conseguido mover todos los ficheros que me interesan a un directorio concreto.

Gracias de antemano.

Nota: se que se podría usar el "|" pero tampoco me ha funcionado para enviar los resultados desde Get-CildItem al bucle

Comment: Gracias por la corrección de la edición

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema venía por 2 lugares:

- El foreach estaba apuntando mal al objeto individual
- El filtro a mi no me funcionó

Así que lo cambié por lo siguiente:

```
$Ficherosamover = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directorioorigen -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike $Excluidos}
foreach ($Fichero in $Ficherosamover) {
    $Archivo = $Fichero.Name
    $Archivo
    $ArchivoDesglosado = $Archivo.Split("_")
        $Cliente = $ArchivoDesglosado[1]
        $Cliente
        $Tipoanalisis = $ArchivoDesglosado[2]
        $Tipoanalisis
        $Año = $ArchivoDesglosado[0]
        $Año
    if(!(Test-Path .\analisis\$Cliente\$TipoAnalisis\$Año)) {
        New-Item -Path .\analisis\$Cliente\$TipoAnalisis\$Año -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null
    }
    Move-Item .\$Archivo .\analisis\$Cliente\$TipoAnalisis\$Año
}
```

Esto va a hacer que cuando ejecuta el **Get-ChildItem** se filtren solo los archivos y usa el pipeline con el **Where-Object** para excluir. Lo segundo es el foreach donde definí **$Fichero** para el objeto individual (cada fichero). Por último agregué un **if** como validación de existencia del directorio (sea el trámite, año o cliente): si no existe, lo crea.

A las órdenes por cualquier consulta! Y espero haber resuelto el problema.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Víctor, entendido los tres cambios: 1. Por un lado el filtro cambiando la opción "-Exclude" por el pipeline y el "-notlike", "-Exclude" esta documentado quizás no lo estoy usando bien, 2. Usar una variable distinta en el foreach "$Fichero" vs "$Ficeheroamover", 3. Crear el directorio es una buena idea para prevenir posibles errores. Muchas gracias.